# How can use Threads in Requesting Perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, request

I'm posting this simple script :
1 open a text file with multiple URLs for a site.
2 The first line gets the address of the site and makes the request.
3 content is verified on the condition.
Threads want to add this script to make faster, but do not know how to do. Please someone could help me in Threads ?

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::Simple;

$sis="$^O";if ($sis eq linux){ $cmd="clear";} else { $cmd="cls"; }
system("$cmd");

if (!$ARGV[0]) {

$sis="$^O";if ($sis eq linux){ $cmd="clear";} else { $cmd="cls"; }
system("$cmd");

print q {
[+] Request.....

};

open( SITE, "< $ARGV[0]" ) or die( "No open: $!" );

our @array = <LINES>;

$numbers = $#array;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $numebers; $i++) {

$url = "$array[$i]";

my $req=HTTP::Request->new(GET=>$url);
my $ua=LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->timeout(15);
my $resposta=$ua->request($req);

if($resposta->content =~ /Exist/) {

print "n t $url n";

open (NOTEPAD, ">> texto.txt");
print NOTEPAD "$url";
close(NOTEPAD);

}
}

print q {

[+] FIM !
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

use Fcntl              qw( LOCK_EX );
use IO::Handle         qw( );
use LWP::UserAgent     qw( );
use Thread::Queue 3.01 qw( );

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 20;

my $output_lock :shared;
my $output_fh;
sub write_to_output_file {
   lock($output_lock);
   print($output_fh @_);
   $output_fh->flush();
}

sub worker {
   my ($ua, $url) = @_;
   my $response = $ua->get($url);
   write_to_output_file("$url\n")
      if $response->success
      && $response->content =~ /Exist/;       
}

{
   $output_fh = \*STDOUT;  # Or open a file.

   my $q = Thread::Queue->new();
   for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
      async {
         my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( timeout => 15 );
         while (my $job = $q->dequeue()) {
            worker($ua, $job);
         }
      };
   }

   while (<>) {
      chomp;
      $q->enqueue($_);
   }

   $q->end();
   $_->join() for threads->list();
}
```

Comment: Might be tempted to make the output sub into a thread as well, and use a Queue to feed it.

Comment: I have the errors:

Global symbol "$fh" requires explicit package name at script.pl line 18.
Global symbol "$fh" requires explicit package name at script.pl line 19.
Execution of script.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Why this error ?

Comment: Ikegami, where can I set the txt file in static format. for example:

$var = "urls.txt"

Comment: The program reads from the file(s) provided as arguments (or STDIN if none provided). This is done by reading from `ARGV`, the default handle for `<>` aka `readline`. Feel free to use a different file handle (e.g `<$fh>`).